# MySQL: Best way to do a backwords full text search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, where-clause

I am trying to do basically a reverse full test search but have no clue of the best way to go about doing it.

Basically I have a table of key phrases laid out like this:
id - phrase
1 - "hello world"
2 - "goodbye world"
3 - "this is my world"

I then have a set string, such as "Welcome to the hello world group".  I want to find the ID of all rows in my table that has an exact match for phrase. Meaning "o the" would not match because the word is "to the".  Also "ello" would not match because the world is "hello".

Using Full Text Search, this can easily be achieved by doing a search of:
AGAINST ('"hello world"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Problem is, I don't believe I can use a full text search, since a full text search would find all rows that contains a single phrase.  I want all phrases (from a known set of phrases) that match a single set.

I know how to do this using RegEx using the following, however this is way to slow. On a table with 400,000 key phrases it took over 40 seconds:

WHERE "the data I know I want to search goes here" REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', `phrases`, '[[:>:]]')

What I need is a more optimized way to do this.  How would I possibly go about doing this as a full text search, even if i have to temporarily add it to a table without actually doing a LOOP individually checking each keyword.

I really appreciate the feedback as this is really causing my site to lag on adding new data.

Comment: To anyone who has a similar issue:

After some more though I ended up testing a theory. What i did was add a column to my keywords table and set that as the keyword, split up by words, then joining with |, making sure it started and ended wth a |. So "hello my world" became "|hello|my|world|". From there, when a new string came in, I did the same, so "lets test hello my world" became "|lets|test|hello|my|world|". With this, I could easily then find exactly hello my world, since it had the start and end | to ensure "shello my world" did not match.

Comment: This took what was a 50 second query with about 400,000 key phrases down to about 1.2 seconds.  Still slow, but enough to allow my app to continue running.  To better optimize this, I may eventually do the search tier as suggested by Jogo, but this is good enough for now due to all the down time this caused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to consider a solution that reads the phrases out of the database and constructs a separate data structure used for optimized phrase detection, there are **two main techniques** that solve the problem. Which one is best for you depends on a number of factors, in particular:

1. How frequently the phrase list is updated
2. Whether and how you tokenise the text before running the phrase detection
3. How long the target strings are

**Option 1: Hash-table of the phrases** This means you simply insert each of the phrases as key into a hash table (aka *dictionary* or *hash map* in many programming languages). The phrase id becomes the value. Updates are fast and easy, but detecting the phrases in a given string can be hard: Firstly you need to tokenise the string and be sure that phrases only occur between token boundaries. Secondly, you need to make a lookup in the hash not only for every token, but also for every pair, triple, quadruple etc. of consecutive tokens. This still works well if the target strings are generally short. You can also maintain a copy of the hash table on disk, e.g. using the Berkeley DB. There are ready-to-use modules in the standard library of most programming languages for this.

**Option 2: Search trie** (or, slightly more advanced, a minimised search trie or a **finite state machine**). This can be implemented in very space-efficient ways but is generally larger than a hash table (although 400k entries will *not* be a problem at all). The big advantage during phrase detection is that you need not cut out tokens (or candidate phrases between token boundaries) before making look-ups. Instead you perform a longest-match look-up at each candidate start position in the text. Storing on disk is possible, although in most programming languages there won't be a standard-library module for this. Updates are quite easy in a trie, but can get difficult (and potentially time-consuming) in a minimised trie or FST.

**Both options** allow the data structure to be maintained on disk (or a copy of it to be stored on disk, while the actual look-ups happen memory). But you won't get transaction safety or fault-tolerance (which I understand you are not looking for).

Comment: Jogo: Thanks for the feedback. I was working on this the night before I went out of town so havn't been able to go over it yet. Finally all caught up so going to look at your options later tonight.  Gave you a vote up for the help and if either work I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up using a less efficient, but simpering solution I though of so that I could easily keep it all in mySQL.  I may eventually try both above for benchmarks, as even mine is "slow", but for now it's enough for me to work with for sure, so I don't have to take the logic totally out of my DB. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use search engine. For example solr. You can set specific search filters against text. + search for words only. + It will be blindingly fast.

Or, second idea you can create your own table that stores all words and id of phrase. and search that table maching words only. It will be faster because you can add index on words better then phrases altogether.

Comment: Well the issue is not the speed of the full text saerch. FTS is extremely fast. The issue is I want to find matching keyphrases to a string, not strings to a key phrase.  Full text search is basically the exact opposite of what I am doing, and so would a Search Engine.  Know what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, now you totally lost me. You have phrases table and some text. And you want to find all phrases ids that is in text. Right?

Comment: That is correct. Doing a search engine seems that i would not be able to do that. I would only be able to find all text that contains a certain phrase.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm just throwing ideas here now. Maybe it is possible to use some kind of sql query that will return all phrases ids that is in searched text.

SELECT DISTINCT(p.id) 
FROM phrases AS p 
INNER JOIN text_table AS t ON t.text LIKE '%' + p.phrase + '%' AND t.id = X

Don't know about this query speed thou.

Comment: well probably with like is  "hello world"  will match "ello world" which it shouldn't.  Reason I was using RegEx, though it is extremely slow.  Sorry for delayed response, went out of town after writing this and forgot about it. Thanks for the input though